# An unhandled exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll while trying to make a HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors

This is my code, I trying to simulate a website visit to a URL , Tried Many like Facebook, Google, Youtube, Blogger, even Microsoft and some forums.
there is an error in the code when I press the button in my app to take the LinkURL.Text and then do the following.  No errors in the error log in VS

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(LinkURL.Text);
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        request.Timeout = 1000;
        request.Method = "Get";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader URLReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            String RequestSent = URLReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

after button press, an error shows up in VS2015 in this line

```
            HttpWebResponse response (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Says

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll
```

Any Suggestions? Am I missing some details to type here?
I just need it "for now" to be counted as a visit, at some point I will take some strings from a website, but I don't need this now, only the visit.

Comment: Can you give an example of the URL you're passing in? It has to be in a format acceptable to the WebRequest.Create() method.

Comment: Actually, My problem was solved and I will answer it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically, I tried visiting a blog and >>

```
    request.timeout = 1000;
```

I tried changing it to 1:10 seconds but nothing changed , everytime says that connection time out so I continued doing some searches till I found that I need to set a ContentLength
so I added

```
request.ContentLength = 0;
```

Tried again with this enabled and it worked, no more exceptions in blogger links and other links which used to have, If someone can explain this it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your trying visit a website say using a button, then you can use the     using system.diagnostic;

Then in the btnClick use the

```
system.diagnostic.process.start("http://www.facebook.com/")
```

This will then send you to face book on the button click.

Comment: thanks, but I want to visit it actually without redirecting.

Comment: like , If i want to get the IP from a site let's say whatismyip .. as a string. I simulate the visit without actually redirecting to whatismyip. got me?

Comment: well if you wanted to do that you could use the xml format. For example when I build voice automated software and I want to get the weather. I pull the xml nodes off yahoo weather. from there I create a string for what I want. then pull the value of the item. For example the temperature would be     String Temp;            then I would use the variable Temp to pull the temperature with out having to even go to the internet web browser. However its a thought

Comment: Actually I'm still a beginner and pulling the string out of a website is the idea that I came with, I think of an app , I walk in the way of making it, try to practise

Comment: Ok I will send more revealing code later today on how to pull a value from a website.